# my node.js user registration is not working with "/auth/registration" but works with "/registration"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I get error cannot POST `/auth/auth/register` with my code but when I change
 `app.get('/auth/register')`**to**`app.get('/register')` the code works fine. Can anyone please tell me where the problem is and it would be a great help if anyone help me in solution .

I have tried changing `app.get('/auth/register')` to other routes like *('/create/registration'), app.get('/Registering/user')* but it doesn't work .Should I should use only `app.get('/userRegister')` or `app.get('createNewUser')` or `app.get('goodRegister')`

```
const express = require('express');
const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const userController = require('./controllers/createUser');
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser');

const app = new express();

app.get('/auth/register', userController);
app.post('/users/register', storeUserController);

const User = require('../database/models/User')
```

}

```
//my controller
module.exports = (req, res) => {
User.create(req.body, (error, user) => {

    res.redirect('/')

})
```

}

```
//my database model
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true

},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

})

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
const user = this
bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(error, encrypted) {
    user.password = encrypted
    next()
})
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);  



app.listen(4000, () => {
console.log("application listening on port 4000")
```

})

```
//my view
<form action="users/register" method="POST"  encType="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a / before "users" in your form action?

Comment: yes I have done that and I get the error cannot POST auth/auth/register

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem myself. thanks to everyone for taking out time to check through and give one explanation or another.
the problem with the code is the path to my controller. the name of the file should not have been `User` but `user` so I changed `const User = require('../database/models/User')` to `const User = require('../database/models/User')` in other to match with the name of the file under the database/model directory